# How to read a class parameter using Caché SQL?

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache, intersystems

How do I read a class parameter using Caché SQL?

`select * from table` does not list any class parameters.

Comment: @MichaelGardner - I mean class parameter: http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GOBJ_classes#GOBJ_classes_parameters

Comment: I'm surprised and disappointed to see this mark closed - it seems we see that happen every now and again when people don't understand the question is for InterSystems Caché.  This is probably a side effect of it being such a niche database product (and possibly the only reference to "Caché" being in the tags, making the question sound really generic).  The question here seems like a perfectly acceptable question for the Caché database, but I don't have enough reputation to vote to reopen this.

Comment: Looks like my flagging this for moderation worked and got this reopened.  I slightly edited the title and question to make it clearer that this isn't a generic SQL question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameters are specific to the **class definition**, not specific to the object or row. Therefore, you cannot find them by querying the class table. Rather, you need to query the Class Definition tables. These reside in the %Dictionary classes.

For this particular query, you can use

```
SELECT * FROM %Dictionary.ParameterDefinition WHERE parent='Sample.Person'
```

In the SAMPLES namespace, this should yield results for all Parameters that are a part of Sample.Person - in this case, only EXTENTQUERYSPEC.

Comment: So the _Default column holds the current value of the parameter?

Comment: _Default contains the default value - the only value stored in the database.